# RedBean php count query with where

Tags: redbean

I need a count query in redbean php with where condision

I used

`R::count("company","country like 'United States'");`

where country name is the where condision

plz suggest some thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redbean expects an array on 3rd parameter, so you should use:

`R::count("company", "country like ?", ["United States"]);`

note that every `?` should match one element in array, but if you have more conditions for the same value, you can also use `:param` once instead, for ex:

`R::count("company", "country like :name OR city like :name", [":name" => "United States"]);`

Answer (score 0):

R::count("company","country like 'United States'");

this works fine.........
but this doesn't
R::count("company","country like '".$country."'");

Comment: How error it throw? I think you are badly quotation marks:  '".$country."'"

Comment: I think you are before $country 3 quotation marks ('") and for you are 4 quotation marks ("").

Comment: thanks @bluray found the error it was before the query execution not in the query